# how to enable hotspot in the action center of win10

Tags: autohotkey

for some reasons, I dont want to run a batch file to start a wifi hotspot.

so yeah, I choose to enable hotspot in the action center with *Click* command in autohotkey.

(I want to press Numpad0 and NumpadEnter to enable it)

(codes below ain't working)

```
~Numpad0 & NumpadEnter::

CoordMode MouseGetPos , Screen

MouseGetPos, X, Y

Send #a

MouseClick , Left, 1496, 796, 1, 10, U

Send #a

MouseClick , L, X, Y, 0, 10, , 

Return
```

The problem is, autohotkey can neither move the mouse cursor onto the button of action center **for unknown reasons** nor then click it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no such [`CoordMode` target type](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm#Parameters) as `MouseGetPos`. You're looking for `Mouse`. Also, I don't think you'll want to just generate a mouse up event (`U` specified in [`DownOrUp`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm)). But the biggest question is why do you want to use mouse click events?

Comment: @0x464e sorry mate I misunderstand the usage of DownOrUp... and I dont really know any other commands to make it work... would you like to recommand some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revision 2.

I hope this helps.

```
~Numpad0 & NumpadEnter::
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 1 ;;Mouse move superfast!
SetKeyDelay, 10, 60 ;;make sure, you dont have [Sendmode, input] at top of your script.
CoordMode, Screen
CoordMode, Mouse
MouseGetPos, X, Y
Send, #a
Sleep 100
MouseMove,1496,796
Click ;;sends left click
Sleep 100
Send, #a
MouseMove, X, Y ;;goes back to Original Pos

return
```

Comment: sorry mate, it doesn't work either... I think mouseclick or click commands can't work at all. Do you have any alternative idea?

Comment: _There is no such CoordMode target type as MouseGetPos_
Now I realize..had missed this one.

This time I made sure everything is right and hopefully should work.

Comment: Thank you for all your work on this! Really appreciated!